# Drupal 7 Views Table Blocks Common Fields Sorting not working in single page

Tags: views

My site having dashboard page where I am displaying multiple Views blocks (2-3) with Table format. Each block have few common fields to display with different filters. These blocks have exposed form as well.
The issue I am facing with SORTING on common fields. The fields which are not common, sorting on those are working as expected. Filter and Paging are also working fine on each block as I have set different page id for those.

Do you have any idea how to make those sorting possible ?
Note: Ajax is ON in each block and machine id is also set different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the Filter identifier under the More fieldset at the bottom of the exposed filters in the View

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is working for node and entity BUT og group have some limitation. Sorting is not working for OG case. Do you have any idea on those ? Please do needful.